# Encrypting and Decrypting Data in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, encryption

I'm trying to use this sample https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW9 , to create  public/private keys and after encrypt some data.

> SecKeyRef publicKey = NULL;                                 // 3
>
> ```
> NSData * publicTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:publicKeyIdentifier
>                                     length:strlen((const char *)publicKeyIdentifier)]; // 4
>
> NSMutableDictionary *queryPublicKey =
> [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; // 5
>
> [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];
> [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
> [queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
> [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(id)kSecReturnRef];
> // 6
>
> status = SecItemCopyMatching
> ((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKey); // 7
> ```

On iOS this works fine.

In OSX I'm getting this when I'm calling SecItemCopyMatching (7) . It is sample provided by Apple. I have no idea what's wrong, might some attributes for query need to be different on OSX?

Thanks

> [NSConcreteData _fastCharacterContents]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x1005440f0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying iOS sample code on OS X, framework is similar but not identical.

You can avoid _fastCharacterContents selector issue by removing kSecClass key, i.e. remove following line of code, it fixes the crash issue but doesn't work correctly

[queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey forKey:(id)kSecClass];

See this quesiton for Mac OS X sample:
[Sample code for public key encryption/decryption on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140664/sample-code-for-public-key-encryption-decryption-on-mac)

Comment: Thanks a lot for an answer. I will try and let you know what happened. At this moment I'm not checking as accepted answer, so might someone else come with other idea. Example I provided is said on the top Mac Developer Library. I guess it should be only iOS.